# Make html input element select-able behind a trasparent image

Tags: html, css

I want an element behind a trasparent image to be select-able please help me !

Comment: Is not hard question, can I do that?

Comment: Select it how? Using a CSS selector, or with the cursor? If the latter, just negate the `z-index` of the image

Comment: No, it's not a hard question, however here at SO you're expected to at least show what you've tried so we can help you find the problem. This is not a site where you come to ask others to do work for you.

Comment: with cursor obviously like this - http://jsfiddle.net/marcellokabora/h2QkR/

Comment: see the jsfiddle exampleeeeee !! help meee !

Comment: Wow. When people ask, it does not seem to be so obvious... What exactly do you mean by "selecting with the cursor"? Could Firebug do the job? What do you want to do with the hidden element?

Comment: Please stop begging & whining... it's not going to help you any faster or better.

Answer (score 2):

Simply change the z-index value to a greater value, such as "99". It still has the exact same appearance on the page but is now click-able, and will accept user input.

Alternatively, you don't have to use absolute positioning for such a layout, you could just position the input with left and top margins and align it against it's container element (and the corresponding background image).

**HTML**

```
<header>
    <input id="input" type="text" name="text" />
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
header {
     background:url('your_url') no-repeat;
     display:block;
     width:960px; /* for example... */
     height:200px; /* for example... */
}
#input {
    margin-left:100px; /* for example... */
    margin-top:80px; /* for example... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove z-index from you input element which you are setting to -1.